# ipad swipe on table row swipes entire page

Tags: ios, ipad, swipe

A page has a column on the left of static content and a table to the right that the visitor wants to scroll through. If they go to swipe the table and their finger lands on the tablerow border, the whole page scrolls up instead of just the table.

Table is a standard table. Any ideas on how to prevent the iPad swipe from 'grabbing' the tablerow border and moving the entire page instead of just swiping the table?

Comment: What do you mean by `tablerow border`? Separator?

Comment: Yes, the border - if their finger hits the tablerow border - the whole page swipes.